# GitLab CI merge request overview does not show test coverage changes

Tags: node.js, jestjs, gitlab, gitlab-ci, test-coverage

In my project I've added to `.gitlab-ci.yml` file regex `coverage: /All files[^|]*\|[^|]*\s+([\d\.]+)/` section to catch test coverage value from coverage reports files and it works. The only issue that it does not show if coverage was increased or decreased:

[image]

Taget branch coverage value:

[image: Target branch coverage value]

I expect to see smth like:

[image]

Maybe it is necessary to add anything else to GilLab setting to make it count percentage diffs?

Answer (score 0):

@TwittorDrive, I faced a similar issue when initially setting up coverage monitoring on my GitLab repository. However, after merging the coverage monitoring into my default branch (in my scenario, the master branch), the issue got resolved. The unit test coverage delta was visible on all the merge requests that were subsequently raised.

Here's my checklist:

- Ensure coverage monitoring runs on both merge requests and the master.
- Incorporate the coverage regex config on the master branch.
- Execute the pipeline on the master branch (your default branch).
- Run the unit test pipeline on existing merge requests.

Once I completed these steps, the test coverage delta was visible on the merge request page.